# How can I make copy of value and store it to array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have calendar, If I click on day, I would like to make copy of this value and store it to Array, and if I click on another day, I would like to get current day copy and add it to array with prev day value. User can select multiple days. How can I do this? I am trying this way

```
const [dates, setDates] = useState([])
   console.log(dates)

   const handleClick = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault()

   const selectedDya = e.target.textContent
   console.log(selectedDya)
   setDates((prev) => ({...prev}, selectedDya))
   }


<section className='week'>
          {data[0][0].map((item, i) => (
              <span key={i}
                  onClick={handleClick}
                  className={'cell'}>
                {item}
             </span>
            ))}
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your click handler function, do this:

```
   const handleClick = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault()

   const selectedDya = e.target.textContent
   console.log(selectedDya)
   setDates((prev) => ([...prev, selectedDya])
   }
```

This adds the newly selected date to your previous array.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few modifications you can make to achieve your desired functionality. Here's an updated version of your code that should work:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const YourComponent = () => {
  const [dates, setDates] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    const selectedDay = e.target.textContent;
    setDates((prev) => [...prev, selectedDay]);
  };

  return (
    <section className='week'>
      {data[0][0].map((item, i) => (
        <span key={i} onClick={handleClick} className={'cell'}>
          {item}
        </span>
      ))}
    </section>
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```